# How can I redirect URLs entered in the browser?

Tags: c#, url, redirect, proxy-server

I want to redirect URLs entered in the browser. For example, when I enter *http://microsoft.com*, it would redirect to *http://127.0.0.1:5000/webpage.html* and show this page. I want to do this for all websites entered in the browser.

I don't want to do it by ASP.NET.

I have 10 computers in a workgroup network. I want to manage them by a system that it is server.

My program has 2 client and server versions. Client versions install on PC Clients.
I want to be able to get the client bandwidth systems, And if the bandwidth is over, I redirect browser to a page or port (127.0.0.1:32500) and I stop communicating with internet for all programs on PC Clients. I know that I use proxy, but how?

If I set proxy for browser, other programs can connect to Internet without cross through the proxies.

I want to make a program like net support schools that I can control internet on client (Web access in net support).

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by creating entries in the Windows HOSTS file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts).

This is a permanent redirect until the hosts files is changed again.

Also, please be aware that Windows maintains a DNS cache, so if you use something like this, you may have to tell windows to flush it's DNS cache.  That can be done by using the command:

```
C:> ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Isn't HOST file handling only IPs as the redirect? He would be able to redirect microsoft.com to 127.0.0.1, but not to port 5000 and /webpage.html.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Yes, you are correct.  I think I misread OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 10 computer,
1-it's better you put a server like one of them and on the server start dns server like 192.168.1.1 and manage all site and ip you want and for clients set dns on you dns server.
2-it's easier, but if your network bigger you can't administer that. You must open every client hosts file (*C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc*) and add row like
127.0.0.1:32500                microsoft.com
if you want change this file you must run as administrator.